# An Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this equation?

$\dfrac{y'-\dfrac{y}{x}}{1+y'\dfrac{y}{x}}=\tan ax$

Or this equation

$\dfrac{y'-\dfrac{y}{x}}{1+y'\dfrac{y}{x}}=ax$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It helps to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ). It helps to tell us what your thoughts are and what you have tried. Also, only one question per posting. Regards

Comment: use wolfram alpha.http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\dfrac{y'-\dfrac{y}{x}}{1+y'\dfrac{y}{x}}=ax$ , $a\neq0$ ,

$\dfrac{xy'-y}{x+yy'}=ax$

$xy'-y=ax^2+axyy'$

$axyy'-xy'=-y-ax^2$

$x(ay-1)\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-y-ax^2$

Let $u=x^2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{dy}{du}\dfrac{du}{dx}=2x\dfrac{dy}{du}$

$\therefore2x^2(ay-1)\dfrac{dy}{du}=-y-ax^2$

$\left(x^2+\dfrac{y}{a}\right)\dfrac{du}{dy}=2\left(\dfrac{1}{a}-y\right)x^2$

$\left(u+\dfrac{y}{a}\right)\dfrac{du}{dy}=2\left(\dfrac{1}{a}-y\right)u$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $v=u+\dfrac{y}{a}$ ,

Then $u=v-\dfrac{y}{a}$

$\dfrac{du}{dy}=\dfrac{dv}{dy}-\dfrac{1}{a}$

$\therefore v\left(\dfrac{dv}{dy}-\dfrac{1}{a}\right)=2\left(\dfrac{1}{a}-y\right)\left(v-\dfrac{y}{a}\right)$

$v\dfrac{dv}{dy}-\dfrac{v}{a}=\left(\dfrac{2}{a}-2y\right)v+\dfrac{2y^2}{a}-\dfrac{2y}{a^2}$

$v\dfrac{dv}{dy}=\left(\dfrac{3}{a}-2y\right)v+\dfrac{2y^2}{a}-\dfrac{2y}{a^2}$

Let $v=-w$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dv}{dy}=-\dfrac{dw}{dy}$

$\therefore w\dfrac{dw}{dy}=\left(2y-\dfrac{3}{a}\right)w+\dfrac{2y^2}{a}-\dfrac{2y}{a^2}$

Let $s=y-\dfrac{3}{2a}$ ,

Then $w\dfrac{dw}{ds}=2sw+\dfrac{2}{a}\left(s+\dfrac{3}{2a}\right)^2-\dfrac{2}{a^2}\left(s+\dfrac{3}{2a}\right)$

$w\dfrac{dw}{ds}=2sw+\dfrac{2s^2}{a}+\dfrac{4s}{a^2}+\dfrac{3}{2a^3}$

Let $t=s^2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dw}{ds}=\dfrac{dw}{dt}\dfrac{dt}{ds}=2s\dfrac{dw}{dt}$

$\therefore2sw\dfrac{dw}{dt}=2sw+\dfrac{2s^2}{a}+\dfrac{4s}{a^2}+\dfrac{3}{2a^3}$

$w\dfrac{dw}{dt}=w+\dfrac{s}{a}+\dfrac{2}{a^2}+\dfrac{3}{4a^3s}$

$w\dfrac{dw}{dt}=w\pm\dfrac{\sqrt t}{a}+\dfrac{2}{a^2}\pm\dfrac{3}{4a^3\sqrt t}$

This exactly belongs to the ODE of the form http://science.fire.ustc.edu.cn/download/download1/book%5Cmathematics%5CHandbook%20of%20Exact%20Solutions%20for%20Ordinary%20Differential%20EquationsSecond%20Edition%5Cc2972_fm.pdf#page=137.

WLOG, just consider $w\dfrac{dw}{dt}=w+\dfrac{\sqrt t}{a}+\dfrac{2}{a^2}+\dfrac{3}{4a^3\sqrt t}$ ,

The general solution is $\begin{cases}t=\dfrac{\left(\sqrt\tau\cos\tau-\dfrac{\sin\tau}{2\sqrt\tau}-C\sqrt\tau\sin\tau-\dfrac{C\cos\tau}{2\sqrt\tau}-\dfrac{\sin\tau}{\sqrt\tau}-\dfrac{C\cos\tau}{\sqrt\tau}\right)^2}{a^2\left(\dfrac{\sin\tau}{\sqrt\tau}+\dfrac{C\cos\tau}{\sqrt\tau}\right)^2}\\w=\dfrac{\tau^2\left(\dfrac{\cos\tau}{\sqrt\tau}-\dfrac{\sin\tau}{2\tau\sqrt\tau}-\dfrac{C\sin\tau}{\sqrt\tau}-\dfrac{C\cos\tau}{2\tau\sqrt\tau}\right)^2-\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\mp\tau^2\right)\left(\dfrac{\sin\tau}{\sqrt\tau}+\dfrac{C\cos\tau}{\sqrt\tau}\right)^2}{a^2\left(\dfrac{\sin\tau}{\sqrt\tau}+\dfrac{C\cos\tau}{\sqrt\tau}\right)^2}\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}t=\dfrac{\left(\sqrt\tau\cos\tau-\dfrac{3\sin\tau}{2\sqrt\tau}-C\sqrt\tau\sin\tau-\dfrac{3C\cos\tau}{2\sqrt\tau}\right)^2}{a^2\left(\dfrac{\sin\tau}{\sqrt\tau}+\dfrac{C\cos\tau}{\sqrt\tau}\right)^2}\\w=\dfrac{\tau^2\left(\dfrac{\cos\tau}{\sqrt\tau}-\dfrac{\sin\tau}{2\tau\sqrt\tau}-\dfrac{C\sin\tau}{\sqrt\tau}-\dfrac{C\cos\tau}{2\tau\sqrt\tau}\pm\dfrac{\sin\tau}{\sqrt\tau}\pm\dfrac{C\cos\tau}{\sqrt\tau}\right)^2-\dfrac{1}{4}\left(\dfrac{\sin\tau}{\sqrt\tau}+\dfrac{C\cos\tau}{\sqrt\tau}\right)^2}{a^2\left(\dfrac{\sin\tau}{\sqrt\tau}+\dfrac{C\cos\tau}{\sqrt\tau}\right)^2}\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}t=\dfrac{(2\tau\cos\tau-3\sin\tau-C(2\tau\sin\tau+3\cos\tau))^2}{4a^2(\sin\tau+C\cos\tau)^2}\\w=\dfrac{(\pm2\tau\sin\tau+2\tau\cos\tau-\sin\tau+C(\pm2\tau\cos\tau-2\tau\sin\tau-\cos\tau))^2-(\sin\tau+C\cos\tau)^2}{4a^2(\sin\tau+C\cos\tau)^2}\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}s^2=\dfrac{(2\tau\cos\tau-3\sin\tau-C(2\tau\sin\tau+3\cos\tau))^2}{4a^2(\sin\tau+C\cos\tau)^2}\\v=\dfrac{(\sin\tau+C\cos\tau)^2-(\pm2\tau\sin\tau+2\tau\cos\tau-\sin\tau+C(\pm2\tau\cos\tau-2\tau\sin\tau-\cos\tau))^2}{4a^2(\sin\tau+C\cos\tau)^2}\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}\left(y-\dfrac{3}{2a}\right)^2=\dfrac{(2\tau\cos\tau-3\sin\tau-C(2\tau\sin\tau+3\cos\tau))^2}{4a^2(\sin\tau+C\cos\tau)^2}\\u=\dfrac{(\sin\tau+C\cos\tau)^2-(\pm2\tau\sin\tau+2\tau\cos\tau-\sin\tau+C(\pm2\tau\cos\tau-2\tau\sin\tau-\cos\tau))^2}{4a^2(\sin\tau+C\cos\tau)^2}-\dfrac{y}{a}\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}\left(y-\dfrac{3}{2a}\right)^2=\dfrac{(2\tau\cos\tau-3\sin\tau-C(2\tau\sin\tau+3\cos\tau))^2}{4a^2(\sin\tau+C\cos\tau)^2}\\x^2=\dfrac{(\sin\tau+C\cos\tau)^2-(\pm2\tau\sin\tau+2\tau\cos\tau-\sin\tau+C(\pm2\tau\cos\tau-2\tau\sin\tau-\cos\tau))^2}{4a^2(\sin\tau+C\cos\tau)^2}-\dfrac{y}{a}\end{cases}$

For $\dfrac{y'-\dfrac{y}{x}}{1+y'\dfrac{y}{x}}=\tan ax$ , $a\neq0$ ,

$\dfrac{xy'-y}{x+yy'}=\tan ax$

$xy'-y=x\tan ax+yy'\tan ax$

$yy'\tan ax-xy'=-y-x\tan ax$

$(y\tan ax-x)y'=-y-x\tan ax$

Let $u=y-x\cot ax$ ,

Then $y=u+x\cot ax$

$y=u+x\cot ax$

$y'=u'+\cot ax-ax\csc^2ax$

$\therefore(\tan ax)u(u'+\cot ax-ax\csc^2ax)=-(u+x\cot ax)-x\tan ax$

$uu'\tan ax+(1-ax\csc ax\sec ax)u=-u-x\tan ax-x\cot ax$

$uu'\tan ax=(ax\csc ax\sec ax-2)u-x\tan ax-x\cot ax$

$uu'=(ax\csc^2ax-2\cot ax)u-x-x\cot^2ax$

$uu'=(ax\csc^2ax-2\cot ax)u-x\csc^2ax$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

In fact all Abel equation of the second kind can be transformed into Abel equation of the first kind.

Let $u=\dfrac{1}{v}$ ,

Then $u'=-\dfrac{v'}{v^2}$

$\therefore-\dfrac{v'}{v^3}=\dfrac{ax\csc^2ax-2\cot ax}{u}-x\csc^2ax$

$v'=(x\csc^2ax)v^3+(2\cot ax-ax\csc^2ax)v^2$

Please follow the method in http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2011/387429/#sec2